# Were Iroquois mourning rituals unique?

Tags: native-americans

A section of the Wikipedia article discussing the [culture of the Iroquois](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iroquois#War) states the following:

> ...Since it was believed that the death of a family member also
>   weakened the spiritual strength of the surviving family members, it
>   was considered crucially important to replace the lost family member
>   by providing a substitute who could be adopted or alternatively could
>   be tortured to provide an outlet for the grief.[163] Hence the
>   "mourning wars".
>
> One of the central features of traditional Iroquois life was the
>   "mourning wars" when Haudenosaunee warriors would raid neighboring
>   peoples in search of captives to replace those Haudenosaunee who had
>   died.[164]

The wiki article cites the following [journal article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1921807?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents):

> War and Culture: The Iroquois Experience Daniel K. Richter The William
>   and Mary Quarterly Vol. 40, No. 4 (Oct., 1983), pp. 528-559

Are there other examples of cultures who practiced ritual kidnapping as a replacement for specific individuals?  If so, did they also torture the kidnapping victims?

Several citations available in this Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iroquois.

Comment: I'm uncomfortable with an unsourced and unflattering characterization of another cuture's religious practices.  i don't claim to speak for the Iroquois, but I think if this were about my ethnicity, I'd find it offensive.  Please revise with citations.

Comment: I suggest a source: https://www.ohio.edu/orgs/glass/vol/1/14.htm

Comment: Nothing for anyone to be offended about. This happened in the 18th century and before. Kidnapping and/or human sacrifice happened in many cultures throughout the world.  Just wondering if theses particular rituals and their reasoning were unique.  Many citations available in this Wikipedia article.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iroquois